# Problemas com operadores de comparação

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um site, e nele possui níveis de acesso por login, sendo "1" == "Aluno", "2" == "Professor" e assim vai...

Tentei fazer um sistema para que se o usuário não estiver com email e senha logados, ele não entra na página, porém quero fazer com que ele verifique também se o tipo do usuário é compativel com a página que ele está entrando.

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
  if(!isset($_SESSION["email"]) || !isset($_SESSION["senha"])) { 
    if($_SESSION["tipo"] != '1'){
      // Usuário não logado! Redireciona para a página de login 
      header("Location: index.php?login"); 
      exit; 
    }
  }
?>
```

Porém ele não está verificando:

```
if($_SESSION["tipo"] != '1'){
```

Como posso fazer para que o operador funcione?
OBS: Este operador tem que ser verificado na tabela do mysql.

Comment: Chegou a verificar se tipo está setada, exibir o valor dela no console, algo assim?

Comment: O console é seu melhor amigo! :D

Comment: Já tentou depurar e ver o conteúdo, utilizar um var_dump na ```$_SESSION["tipo"]```?

Comment: Ainda não tentei, como que posso fazer com var_dump?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Deve ter vários exemplos aqui no site, pesquisa assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=var_dump+%5Bphp%5D

Comment: Fiz desta forma mas deu erro:         $teste = if($_SESSION["tipo"] != '1'){
        var_dump($teste);

Comment: vai na minha dica, se não souber debugar aprenda que isso vai te poupar muitas horas de dor de cabeça, mesmo assim se não quiser aprender ou não tiver tempo, vai printando tudo no console.

Comment: é que utilizei método if, por isso não funcionou..

Comment: Um exemplo: https://repl.it/repls/WindingMediumorchidPhysics

Comment: O mais estranho é que passando para o meu aqui, não aparece nada no console, e a aplicação não funciona...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((empty($_SESSION['email'])) || (empty($_SESSION['senha'])) || (empty($_SESSION['tipo']))){       
  header("Location: index.php");
}else{
  if($_SESSION['tipo'] != "1"){
      header("Location: index.php");
  }
}
```

Para resolver tive que fazer da seguinte forma acima: